# Incompatible types boolean cannot be converted to String

Tags: java

Lo que pasa es que estoy realizando una aplicacion de biblioteca y al realizar el botón Guardar me sale este error:

> Incompatible types boolean cannot be converted to String

aquí les dejo el código:

Boton Guardar:

```
Connection con=null;
        try{
            con=getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO clientes (rutClientes, Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno, Direcciones, Telefonos, Correos, FechaNac) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            if(ps.setString(1, txtRut.getText().equals(""))){ (AQUI ME SALE EL ERROR)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo de RUT");
            }
            if(txtNombre.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo de NOMBRE");
            }
            if(txtApellidoPaterno.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo de APELLIDO PATERNO");
            }
            if(txtApellidoMaterno.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo de APELLIDO MATERNO");
            }
            if(txtDireccion.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo DIRECCION");
            }
            if(txtTelefono.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo TELEFONO");
            }
            if(txtCorreo.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo CORREO");
            }
            if(txtFechaNac.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo de FECHA DE NACIMIENTO");
            }
            int res=ps.executeUpdate();
            if(res>0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se ejecuto correctamente");
                limpiarCajas();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al ejecutar la conexion");
                limpiarCajas();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que esto obtiene un `boolean` ya que estas realizando una comparación:

```
txtRut.getText().equals("")
```

Pero el método [setString(int parameterIndex, String x)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-) solo permite recibir un `int` y un `String` y no un `int` y un `booleano`.

debes cambiar a solo obtener el valor del texto mediante `txtRut.getText()`, no usando el método `equals()`.

```
ps.setString(1, txtRut.getText());
```

Ahora otro problema, [setString(int parameterIndex, String x)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-)  no devuelve ningún valor por lo que es incorrecto definirlo dentro de un if

```
 if(ps.setString(1, txtRut.getText())){ 
  ...
```

Debes llamar este método y no usarlo dentro del `if()` :

```
 try{
            con=getConnection();
            ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO clientes (rutClientes, Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno, Direcciones, Telefonos, Correos, FechaNac) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1, txtRut.getText());

            if(txtRut.getText().equals("")){ 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo de RUT");
            }
            if(txtNombre.getText().equals("")){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene el campo de NOMBRE");
            }
            ...
            ...
```

Comment: Ahora me sale este error: incompatible types void cannot be converted to boolean :(

Comment: Revisa la actualización , no me había percatado de ese otro problema @nicolasyo1WWE

Comment: Ahi funcionó, muchas gracias men!!